# Handle multiple controls updates to meet some conditions

Tags: javascript, state-management

I have a set of toggles representing user permissions. Below is the list of toggles:

```
 Regular permissions
 [x] writeArticles

 Administrative permissions
 [x] accessDash
 [ ] manageBlog
 [ ] manageSpecialPages
 [x] manageAccounts
 [ ] manageAccountPermissions
```

Thing is they depend on each other, or... some of them, at least, in the following way:

- if `manageAccountPermissions` is `on`, `manageAccounts` will be `on`
- if any of the administrative permissions are on, `accessDash` will be `on`
- if `accessDash` is on, `writeArticles` will be `on`.

Now the thing is reciprocally valid, so:

- if `manageAccounts` turns off then `manageAccountPermissions` turns off
- if `accessDash` turns off then all the administrative permissions turn off
- if `writeArticles` turns off then `accessDash` turns off (implicitly, all the administrative permissions turn off)

---

This is my code so far. This is total crap, and seems to work only for some cases and is also very slow as far as I see:

```
handleToggle = ( event, toggled ) => {
    const targetId = event.target.id;
    const { permissions } = this.state;

    let newPermissions = {
        ...permissions,
        [targetId]: toggled,
    };

    if ( newPermissions.writeArticles === false ) {
        newPermissions.accessDash = false;
    }

    const activeAdminPerm =
        filter( newPermissions, ( o, k ) => o === true && k !== 'writeArticles' );
    if ( Object.size( activeAdminPerm ) &&
        targetId !== 'accessDash' &&
        targetId !== 'writeArticles' ) {
        newPermissions.writeArticles = true;
        newPermissions.accessDash = true;
    }

    if ( newPermissions.accessDash === false || !newPermissions.writeArticles ) {
        for ( let key in permissions ) {
            if ( permissions.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                if ( key !== 'writeArticles' ) {
                    newPermissions[key] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    this.setState( {
        permissions: newPermissions,
    } );
};
```

What is the easiest and most logical method to use here? Thank you very much!

---

I wrote [a pen](http://codepen.io/victorbarbu/pen/xOYAyd/) illustrating the code above (with little adaptations)

Comment: I think the best idea is to create a custom event and then attach it to DOM elements: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-custom-events/

Comment: @DavidP could you please elaborate?

Comment: Basically you want to create an Event Handler routine that will check the checked status of each of the relevant checkboxes, and then based on your logic, your check or uncheck other checkboxes based on your logic. Sure you could come up with several functions to do this, and then add them to the onchanged or onclick events of the tag, but that would not be good programming form. This also allows you to fire the event conditionally, so that if two or more things have to happen to check or uncheck another box, you can wait for that to happen, instead of constantly checking.

Comment: @DavidP do I really need a custom event for changing the state of the form when I already have the built-in state manager of React?